# Image button icon not appearing on certain devices Android

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

In my Android app I've added this Image button:

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/soundButton"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

While testing on emulator and my nexus 4 it's working. But when I tried testing it on other phones, it just don't show up. Why?

Comment: Probably there is not enough space to display it in some screens. Could you post the entire layout?

Comment: it could be despaired while rendering

Comment: code looks fine may be layout rendering issue

Comment: @OussemaAroua how to fix it then?

Comment: try changing the view height and width for test purpose and position center

Answer (score 0):

You could try copying the image file to the app/src/main file. Android studio makes images of different sizes to fit different screens. What might be happening, as Juan Cruz Soler said, is that the image is too big to be displayed.